# Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set from Kafka rest proxy

Tags: apache-kafka, aws-msk, kafka-rest

I am trying to use kafka rest proxy for AWS MSK cluster.

MSK Encryption details:

**Within the cluster**

TLS encryption: Enabled

**Between clients and brokers**

TLS encryption: Enabled

Plaintext: Not enabled

I have created topic "TestTopic" on MSK and then I have created another EC2 instance in the same VPC as MSK to work as Rest proxy. Here are details from kafka-rest.properties:

```
zookeeper.connect=z-3.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:2181,z-1.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:2181
bootstrap.servers=b-1.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:9096,b-2.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:9096
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="username" password="password";
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
ssl.truststore.location=/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

I have also created rest-jaas.properties file with below content:

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required
  username="username"
  password="password";
};
```

and then set the java.security.auth.login.config using:

```
export KAFKA_OPTS=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/ec2-user/confluent-6.1.1/rest-jaas.properties
```

After this I started Kafka rest proxy using:

```
./kafka-rest-start /home/ec2-user/confluent-6.1.1/etc/kafka-rest/kafka-rest.properties
```

But when I tried to put an event on the TestTopic by calling service from postman:
POST: http://IP_of_ec2instance:8082/topics/TestTopic
I am getting 500 error. But in the EC2 instance I can see error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:441)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:291)
    at io.confluent.kafkarest.ProducerPool.buildNoSchemaProducer(ProducerPool.java:120)
    at io.confluent.kafkarest.ProducerPool.buildBinaryProducer(ProducerPool.java:106)
    at io.confluent.kafkarest.ProducerPool.<init>(ProducerPool.java:71)
    at io.confluent.kafkarest.ProducerPool.<init>(ProducerPool.java:60)
    at io.confluent.kafkarest.ProducerPool.<init>(ProducerPool.java:53)
    at io.confluent.kafkarest.DefaultKafkaRestContext.getProducerPool(DefaultKafkaRestContext.java:54)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:141)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:106)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:92)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:139)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:74)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:449)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:430)
    ... 71 more
```

I can also see that value of sasl.jaas.config = null in the ProducerConfig values.

Could someone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was fixed. I am updating the fix here so that it can be beneficial for someone:

kafka-rest.properties file should have below text:

```
zookeeper.connect=z-3.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:2181,z-1.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:2181
bootstrap.servers=b-1.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:9096,b-2.msk.xxxx.xx.xxxxxx-1.amazonaws.com:9096
client.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="username" password="username";
client.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
client.sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-512
```

Neither there was a need to create file rest-jaas.properties nor export KAFKA_OPTS was needed.

After these changes, I was able to put the messages in the kafka topic using scram authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and added below properties for the client configuration as mentioned in developers guide at AWS. This solved my problem.This is for enabling communication with MSK cluster using IAM.

```
ssl.truststore.location=<PATH_TO_TRUST_STORE_FILE>

security.protocol=SASL_SSL

sasl.mechanism=AWS_MSK_IAM

sasl.jaas.config=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;

sasl.client.callback.handler.class=software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler
```

for ssl.truststore.location=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/security/cacerts

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/iam-access-control.html